# LANPR download URL

Tags: rendering, npr

I want to use the function called Blender LANPR, but I don`t know where to download it.
Please tell me the download URL.

Comment: [Google](https://bfy.tw/OYWt)

Answer (score 2):

The main page of the branch is at graphically and its URL  is this:

https://blender.community/c/graphicall/1hbbbc/

If you want a direct download then the URL is this:

https://blender.community/5db28f519c12217257836681/download/5ec024c09c12217b155608e7